# Is it possible to change calling convention in gcc for x64?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, clang, calling-convention

I’m writing a C program where I intercept the arguments to a function called by pointer before changing them and forwarding the call to the actual function, and this forwarding is done in assembly. I know that when compiling to x86 it’s possible to mark the calling convention on a per-function basis using **attribute**((stdcall)) so I need to know two things:

1. Is it possible to change the calling convention gcc uses in x64 mode, or is that only available in 32 bit programs?
2. If it is possible, can those, or similar annotations be applied to function pointers so I can ensure the functions are called properly?

I am open to using other compilers if they support this and gcc does not.

Answer (score 2):

GCC supports two calling conventions on x86-64: the System V ABI conventions used on most Unix-like systems, and the Microsoft x64 convention used on Windows.  You can choose a specific one for a function with `__attribute__((ms_abi))` or `__attribute__((sysv_abi))`.  These attributes can also be applied to function pointers.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#x86-Function-Attributes

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cGqbT7sjP).  Notice that `foo1` and `ptr1` have their arguments passed in `ecx` and `edx` per the MS convention, while `foo2` and `ptr2` use `edi` and `esi` as per SysV.

clang behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

**x86-32** (x86)

- **stdcall** and **cdecl** exist

**x86-64** (x64)

- **stdcall** and **cdecl** do not exist
- if used on **Windows** they both refer to Microsoft x64 calling convention (**ms_abi**)
- if used on **UNIX-like**, they both refer to System V AMD64 ABI (**sysv_abi**)
- **ms_abi** and **sysv_abi** exist (for Windows and UNIX-like respectively)

See on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions)